# Why does the Super User Blog have the same styles as the Server Fault Blog?

Tags: bug, status-completed, superuser-blog

It seems that the [Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) is using the same stylesheet as the [Server Fault Blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/). Shouldn't we have our own colors? Maybe something like so:

[image]

instead of what we have now:

[image]

**Edit:** After further research I can confirm that they do in fact use the same stylesheets:

[Server Fault's Stylesheet](http://blog.serverfault.com/wp-content/themes/zimpleza/style.css)

[Super User's Stylesheet](http://blog.superuser.com/wp-content/themes/zimpleza/style.css)

Comment: Does it also use the same stylesheet as the SO blog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed.

Links & blockquotes are now in 'SU style'.

I'll have a closer look through later to see what else can use similar CSS.

Answer (score 4):

This is mainly because we only just recently moved to being officially hosted by Stack Exchange.  I'm assuming, but not for sure, that we just used the default blogging style used by ServerFault.  I'm sure that in time that we can start moving over to a more personalized style for the blog and in fact have already started moving towards that way in small ways.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can!

The Super User blog is hosted by Stack Exchange, but it is run by members of your community.  The theme is the same, but the SU members that are administrators of the blog should be able to edit the css stylesheet as they see fit to make it SU's own.

Comment: Well I guess I have to put one of my 'minions' to work on that then